# HTML- How do i fill up the webpage

Tags: html, space

I been having a fiddle with HTML and have been trying to create my own webpage. My question is how do I fill up the remaining space, without having to type lots of text, as at the moment there is a space between article and footer and the footer with the bottom of the webpage. I have tried adding height: 100% but nothing happens when I do that, I also tried adding a div.container but that didn't seem to do anything either. Many thanks for any help

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

header {
padding: 1em;
color: yellow;
background-color: purple;
clear: left;
text-align: center;
}
footer {
padding: 1em;
color: red;
background-color: green;
clear:left;
text-align:center;
}
nav {
float: left;
max-width: 160px;
margin: auto;
display: inline-block;
padding: 1em;
background-color: red;
color: green;
}
nav.ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
height: 100%;
}
section {
padding: 1em;
background-color: blue;
color: orange;
}
article {
padding: 1em;
background-color: orange;
color: blue;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: 170px;
border: 5px solid gray;
display: block;
}
aside {
padding: 1em;
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>This is a header</h1>
</header>
<nav>This is navigation bar
<ul>
<li><a href="#">nav 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">nav 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">nav 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">nav 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">nav 5</a></li>
</nav>
<section>This is a section</section>
<article>This is an article</article>
<footer>This is a footer</footer>
<aside>This is aside</aside>
</html>
```

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve? Do you want to footer on the bottom of the page all the time? Or below the bottom if the content is more than the height of the page? Which section are you trying to have fill the space between the article and the footer? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I want the footer to rest at the bottom of the web page, then the article to fill the rest of the space between it and the footer and to have the navigation bar fill up all the space between it and the footer

Answer (score 0):

Who doesn't like attractive stuff to see when they visit a site?
I'd say u may add some pic or even your pic(if its your personal webpage).

U may even compromise with the footer part for this.
I hope you are are already displaying what you intended to.
So now, better add some things that are visually appealing.